# Merge multiple old commits in git which have already been pushed?

Tags: git

I have a bunch of old commits which I have already pushed. These are small changes 'e.g. typos', and I want to merge them together so that I don't have 100s of similar commits.

e.g. this:

> 7af8cee5715e266bf249891cf66f832cf8bb6606 typo
>   53104d19d1e2eba92baf36b8384100c461e417c1 typo
>   9e5afd2afc5d6051f568ce3a441eebf087c9ea46 typo
>   fb8be7c9c54ae2d9ee3ed15971de49104729e4d6 ok
>   48828aaf959ee76d77a74dc35b8455542d0dbb8b fixed links
>   6387e73bd692024acbb67c1a843348dd6bd01bb8 fixed link
>   baff3fc602faab37fbd0bf7df9c61ff367121985 fixed htaccess issue
>   2b3e66c19af49030a1da16f9fb7955c4d0f9aa3e fixed htaccess issue
>   5224690d2a44ec0c4872bedb3b54fb55af75530a fixed iplogging issue

Note: These are not directly behind the last commit, these are from months ago.

Comment: This would require rewriting history in your repository.  Would you be comfortable with that?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I'm only pushing to a web server repository which is accessed only by me, so yes.

Comment: Then take a look at the [Rewriting History](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) chapter of the progit book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only option is to perform an interactive rebase on the commits and force-push the rewritten commits to the server-side repository. I recommend you keep the history as-is if the commits since then contain merge commits.

1. First, find the SHA of the first commit you want to change, e.g. `522469`.
2. Check if other branches have been merged since: `git log --oneline --merges 522469~1`. If this generates output, do not run the interactive rebase.
3. Start the interactive rebase: `git rebase --interactive 522469~1`
4. git will present you the list of commits starting at `522469` that you may reorder. Change the `pick` command (first column) to either `squash` or `fixup` for commits you want to meld.
5. Reorder and `squash/fixup` to your heart's content, save the file and close the editor.
6. After the interactive rebase is done, check your build.
7. As the last step, force-push rewritten history to the remote repository: `git push --force origin HEAD`

Some things to keep in mind:

- If there are merge commits, the interactive rebase will remove them. So please don't `git rebase --interactive` if #2 generated output.
- The interactive rebase only affects the current branches' commits (i.e. reachable by `HEAD`). Any branches based off of any commits in the editor window (`git branch --contains 522469`) will need to be rebased off their rewritten counterparts. So there might be more work involved than displayed above. Check `git rebase --onto`.
- In the future, when you find that you need to change/fix the most recent commit, use `git commit --amend` to rewrite the `HEAD` commit instead of creating a new commit. Another option is to `git rebase --interactive` with less commits (e.g. not from months ago but say 2 hours ago, `HEAD~10`) which might present less potential for conflicts.