# How can I join two pushed commits?

Tags: git, github

How can I join two pushed commits?

For example:
I have a commit fixing a typo and a commit changing a text file.
I want to join both and keep only the one which says "changing a text file" on the commit log.

How can I do it?

Comment: why you need to do that, if you pushed two times it should show two commits

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge multiple old commits in git which have already been pushed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28148987/merge-multiple-old-commits-in-git-which-have-already-been-pushed)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can use [`git rebase -i` and `fixup`](https://help.github.com/articles/about-git-rebase/) to rewrite the history and merge commit 2 into commit 1.

Because you already pushed the changes, beware that it is generally not recommended to rewrite the history after the changes has been pushed to a remote repository, because other clients may have already downloaded the changes and you may cause troubles with future updates.

If you are fully aware of what you are doing, use `rebase` to rewrite the history, and push the changes with the `--force` flag: `git push -f`.